# Tensorflow - logistic regression -oneHot Encoder - Transformed array of different size for both train and test

Tags: tensorflow, logistic-regression

```
  x_train = tr1.loc[:, ['Sepal Length', 'Sepal Width', 'Petal Length', 'Petal Width']]
#x_train.shape - (120 x 4)

y_train = tr1.loc[:, ['Species']]
#shape - 120 x 3

x_test = test1.loc[:, ['Sepal Length', 'Sepal Width', 'Petal Length', 'Petal Width']]
#shape 30 x 4
y_test = test1.loc[:, ['Species']]
# shape 30 x 3

oneHot = OneHotEncoder()
oneHot.fit(x_train)
# transform
x_train = oneHot.transform(x_train).toarray()
 # fit our y to oneHot encoder
 oneHot.fit(y_train)
 # transform
 y_train = oneHot.transform(y_train).toarray()

 oneHot.fit(x_test)
 # transform
 x_test = oneHot.transform(x_test).toarray()
 # fit our y to oneHot encoder
  oneHot.fit(y_test)
   # transform
  y_test = oneHot.transform(y_test).toarray()

   print("Our features X_test1 in one-hot format")
    print(x_test)
```

Shape of x_train:  (120, 15)
Shape of y_train:  (120, 3)
Shape of x_test:  (30, 14)
Shape of y_test:  (30, 3)

a) After conversion why is the size x_test = 30 x 14  I assume it has to be  30 x 15 ?

```
# hyperparameters
learning_rate = 0.0001
num_epochs = 100
display_step = 1

# for visualize purpose in tensorboard we use tf.name_scope
with tf.name_scope("Declaring_placeholder"):
# X is placeholdre for iris features. We will feed data later on
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 15])
# y is placeholder for iris labels. We will feed data later on
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])
```

with tf.name_scope("Declaring_variables"):
    # W is our weights. This will update during training time
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([15, 3]))
    # b is our bias. This will also update during training time
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3]))

```
with tf.name_scope("Declaring_functions"):
# our prediction function
y_ = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W), b))
```

b) did I define x, y, W, b correctly because when I run the accuracy I get this error "ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (30, 14) for Tensor 'Declaring_placeholder_10/Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 15)'
"

Comment: See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/54052/55122

Answer (score 6):

Your shape is `(30, 14)` and not `(30, 15)` because there are only 14 unique values in your test (one is missing). In any case you **shouldn't fit the encoder on the test set**, just on the training set. Then just transform on the test set and you'll get the correct dimensions.

Also as far as I can see W and b are declared correctly. I'd ask however you take a minute to format your question a bit better next time.

Comment: Thank you @jcart, this helped! Sure, I agree , the text is quite messed up and I will take care of it next time.